# c# code exits and re-executes when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, loops

My code works for the most part, I tried finding a solution online but struggled to find my exact issue. Here's the code, in C#:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int maxFilm = 5;
        int minFilm = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("We are currently showing:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Rush");
        Console.WriteLine("2. How I live now");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Thor");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Filth");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Planes");
        const int minAge1 = 15;
        const int minAge2 = 12;
        const int minAge3 = 18;
        int filmNumber;
        string filmNum;
        int age;
        string stringAge;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the film you wish to see: ");
            filmNum = Console.ReadLine();
            filmNumber = Int32.Parse(filmNum);
            if (filmNumber > maxFilm || filmNumber < minFilm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid film number");
            }
        }
        while (filmNumber > maxFilm || filmNumber < minFilm);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your age: ");
            stringAge = Console.ReadLine();
            age = Int32.Parse(stringAge);
            if (age < 5 || age > 120)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid age");
            }
        } while (age < 5 || age > 120);


        if (((filmNumber == 1 || filmNumber == 2) && age >= minAge1) || (filmNumber == 3 && age >= minAge2) || (filmNumber == 4 && age >= minAge3) || (filmNumber == 5))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enjoy the film");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are too young");
        }
```

Input:
First, invalid movie number
Second, valid movie number
Third, age between 5-120

Expected output: Either "You are too young" or "enjoy the film" and then the code exits
What happens: The code exits and then re-executes from the start.
If I put a valid film number to start with, then it performs as expected. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What happened (that you didn't expect) when you debugged through it, line by line?

Comment: You can't enter an age until a valid film number is entered, so I'm not sure what your question is... Perhaps share your actual inputs and expected vs actual results ?

Comment: Also you should use Int32.TryParse instead of Int32.Parse. That way you don't crash if use enters text.

Comment: @GrantWinney - I know the age limits are weird, it's part of a problem set I'm working through (not for school, for my own learning - yellow book labs)

Comment: @John3136 - Actual input: I put 0 for film number, it rejects it and repeats the question. Once I put a valid number in (1-5) it asks for age. Once I put the age in the program closes and reopens from the beginning. This only happens if I first put an invalid film number (i.e. if I start with a value from 1-5, then the age portion works as expected)

Comment: @KrystianB - thanks for the tip, I'll definitely change that

Answer (score 2):

After your final Console.WriteLine(), add a Console.ReadLine()
Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enjoy the film");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Also if you don't want the program to close after this, I suggest putting the program into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to see out put, so you can use following code :

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

or

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

To put entire code. generally, in loop is not good idea.